# Passing form label as argument to sub

Tags: vba, excel

I have a function meant to extract a portion of a label in a form.

```
Public Sub setLabelForRefresh(lbl As Label)
    Dim i As Integer
    i = 0 'InStr(1, lbl.Caption, "de")
    Debug.Print i
End Sub

Public Sub callit()
     setLabelForRefresh (frmMain.lblBalancete)
End Sub
```

However I get type mismatch when I run it.

I tried MSForms.Label and passing it ByVal and ByRef.

Any ideas?

Comment: VB.Net IsNot excel-vba

Comment: My bad. I'll edit if possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it like this.

Accept it as an MSForms.Label

```
Private Sub setLabelForRefresh(ByRef lbl As MSForms.Label)
    MsgBox (lbl.name)
    MsgBox (lbl.Caption)
End Sub
```

`Call` you sub and pass it the label.

```
Private sub callit()
    Call setLabelForRefresh(Me.Label1)
End if
```

Or as Rory pointed out.  Don't use parentheses.

```
Private sub callit()
    setLabelForRefresh Me.Label1
End if
```

Comment: Or just remove the parentheses: `setLabelForRefresh Me.Label1`